# Skip videos in youtube using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question is like there are 10 videos running one after another in youtube , some of the videos get the "Skip video" option while other's just don't. Now how can I skip the videos which get the option of skipping and just run the other one's as it is. Also youtube uses flash so what api do I need to use for automating it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Note*** :  This is an idea which you would have to code. Please don't hesitate.

```
if(<skip button is available>) { 
     click Skip button 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement skipButton = driver.findElement(<locator>);

If(skipButton.isDisplayed())
{
  skipButton.click();
}
```